# Multiple ids with one form

Tags: php, mysql

I don't really know how to explain what I want but I'll try. I know my code is horrid and a big mess, I'm just really bad :/ any help would be appreciated.

I'm making a shop for my game, and have a database that lists the pokemon/price/type/id of the pokemon in the shop. Right now I have it almost working, it displays all the pokemon in the shop and they all have a buy button underneath them, but for some reason no matter what pokemon you try to buy it only buys the one on the top of the list. I hope I explained it well enough here is my code.

```
if ($_POST['A'] == '1' ) {
    $token= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);
    $tokenn = strip_tags($token);

    $sql234 = "SELECT * FROM ticketshop";
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticketshop");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $sql23 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."')";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "You have ".$row['ticket']." Tickets" ;
            echo "<p></p>" ;
            if (isset($_POST['slot1'])) {
                if ($row['ticket'] >= $row2['price']) {
                    echo "You have bought ".$row2['pokemon']."" ;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ticket=ticket-".$row2['price']." WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
                        or die(mysql_error());

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_pokemon 
            (pokemon, belongsto, exp, time_stamp, slot, level, type) VALUES ('".$row2['pokemon']."','".$_SESSION['username']."', 100,'".time()."','0', '5', '".$row2['type']."' )") 
                        or die(mysql_error());  
                } else {
                    echo "You can't afford ".$row2['pokemon']."";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticketshop");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        $battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

        echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$battle_get2['pic'].'" border=0>
        </a>' ; 

        $idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row2['id']);
        $iddd = strip_tags($idd);
?>

</span>
<form name="slot1" action="" method="post">
  <div align="center">
    <p>
      <span>
        <select name="A" id="" >
          <option value="1">Buy</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php  echo $iddd ;  ?>" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Accept" name="slot1">
        </span></p>
    </div>
</form>
<span>

<?php
        echo $row ['pokemon'];

?>

</span>
<p></p>
<span>

<?php
        echo "type:";
        echo $row ['type'];
?>

</span>
<p></p>
<span>

<?php
        echo "price:";
        echo $row['price'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should start with correct indentation.

Comment: You should also use PDO if you can help it, `mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: your codes totally in bad structure..? would mind to explain how your codes flow from selecting to submittin?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out on my own, thanks anyways!

Comment: what's the solution? Please create an answer for it in the section below, then select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark by it. This will help others correct similar issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below you are doing wrong:

$sql234 = "SELECT * FROM ticketshop";
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticketshop");

here you are not adding any conditions for fetching the particular record, please see corrections below:

$sql234 = "SELECT * FROM ticketshop where <<FIELD NAME>> = '".$token."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql234);
```